# Can i forget about the post loop inside the page template?

Tags: page-template

A simple `page.php` template often looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
        <?php comments_template( ’, true ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So there is a while loop for post's inside.

But I do not have several "pages" rendered out in any case. Is what assume!

E.g. for archive's this loop makes totally sense.

---

### Now to my question

I would like to structure the template like the following example:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php a_special_content_output_before_the_main_container(get_title()); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
        <?php comments_template( ’, true ); ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This would mean if this while loop has two items inside I will get invalid markup, because of **duplicated id selectors**.

Is there a situation a page can have several entries. 
Means that `have_posts()` is bigger 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On single page and post templates the main loop is only ever going to contain one post, so you don't need to worry about duplicate IDs in your example.

Comment: so this is just a WordPress historical thingy behaviour. because pages are stored as post's in general, i guess.